# Describe $R=\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-3,2X+4)$

Tags: ring-theory

> I need to describe a ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-3,2X+4)$

I know that its element would be of the form $\{f(x)+(X^2-3,2X+4)|f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[X]\}$
After that will i divide $f(x)$ by $X^2-3$ first and then by $2X+4$ to reduce the elements  in $R$?

Comment: First, perhaps, it would help to better understand $I=(x^2-3,2x+4)\leq\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: how do we reduce $f(x)$?

Comment: See also the answers to this [duplicate question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/613978/242), whicg give further details and reamrks.

Answer (score 10):

it looks to me like it is $\mathbb Z_2[X]/\left<X^2+1\right>$.

$2$ is in your ideal because:

$$2 = 2(X^2-3)-(2X+4)(X-2)$$

Also $X^2+1$ is in your ideal because:
 $$\begin{align}X^2+1 &= (X^2-3) + 4 = (X^2-3) + 4(X^2-3) - (2X+4)(2X-4)  \\&= 5(X^2-3) - (2X+4)(2X-4) \end{align}$$

So we know that $\left<2,X^2+1\right>$ is contained in your ideal.

But it is obvious that the generators for your ideal are in $\left<2,X^2+1\right>$.

So we are done.

Note: Given that $(X+1)^2=X^2+1$ in $\mathbb Z_2$, this can be rewritten as isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2[Y]/\left<Y^2\right>$ with $Y$ corresponding to $X+1$.

Comment: Fancy footwork with the generators :)

Comment: I actually started with $2x^2$ and write it as both $2(x^2-3) + 6$ and $(2x+4)x - 8x$. @rschwieb

Comment: The ideal is also $\left<2,X^2-1\right>$, and so the quotient ring is $\mathbb Z_2[u]$, with $u^2=1$.

Comment: $u^2=-1$ or $u^2=1$ doesn't really matter in $\mathbb Z_2$, @lhf. I think the reduction to $\mathbb Z_2[Y]/\left<Y^2\right>$ is probably best.

Comment: Right, and that can be written as $\mathbb Z_2[w]$ with $w^2=0$, which may be more concrete for the OP.

Comment: Perhaps. I always translate "$\mathbb R[w]$ with $P(w)=0$" as $\mathbb R[X]/\left<P(x)\right>$ in my head, @lhf. : )

Comment: And, of course $2x^2 = (2x+4)x-4x$. My previous comment said $-8x$.

Answer (score 1):

I have another answer.
$\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-3,2x+4) = (\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-3))/(x^2-3,2x+4)/(x^2-3)$(by third isomorphism theorem)
now define a map $\mathbb Z[x]$ to $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{3}], $
$F(f(x))=f(\sqrt{3})$( evaluated at root $3)$
then $F$ is surjective homomorphism.By 1st isomorphism theorem 
$\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-3)=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{3}]$
and $(x^2-3,2x+4)/(x^2-3)=(2x+4+(x^2-3))$ and when it undergoes $F$,resultant ideal will be $(2\sqrt{3}+4)$
so finally description will be $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{3}]/(2\sqrt{3}+4)$