# In $Z[x]$, which pairs of $a,b$ commute as modulo operators, such that ($c$ mod $a$) mod $b =$ ($c$ mod $b$) mod $a$ for every $c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In $Z[x]$, which pairs of $a,b$ commute as modulo operators, such that ($c$ mod $a$) mod $b =$ ($c$ mod $b$) mod $a$ for every $c$?

What I got so far is:

Clearly the equasion holds for every pair where one polynomial divides the other.

Another group of pairs are these with $deg(a)=0$ and lead_coeff$(b)=1$.

However, especially the second group seems pretty arbitrary, and it feels like I am missing the bigger picture. Is there a neccessary and sufficient condition for $a,b$?

Comment: What do you mean by "c mod a" *preecisely*? What is x^2 mod 3x  for example?

Comment: @quid `c mod a` is defined like in `Z`: The smallest positive r such that c=b*a+r. In other words, you do polynomial division and output the rest.
`3x` never fits into `x^2` in `Z[X]`, so `x^2 mod 3x=x^2`. A better example would be `(7x^2-3) mod (2x+1): (7x^2-3)=(2x+1)*(3x-2)+(x^2+x-1) -> result:(x^2+x-1)`.

Comment: $\Bbb Z[x]\,$ does not enjoy (Euclidean) division-with-remainder. What do you mean by "smallest"?  When you divide $x^2$ by $3x$ why is your "remainder" $x^2$ vs. $x^2\!-3x?$ Why is the former "smaller"? Perhaps you meant $\,\Bbb Q[x]\,$ vs. $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,?$

Comment: @BillDubuque By smallest I meant the smallest positive. But I am a little confused right now, because I am unsure if that is the correct definition. I'll try if I can find it, but unfortunately most definitions seem to be given in Q[x], while I infact meant to ask the question for Z[x].

Comment: @BillDubuque `(a mod b)` in `Z[x]` should be the representative of `a` in `Z[x]/b`. Can we derive the definition from that?

Comment: What is your procedure for choosing "the representative" element of the coset $\, a + b\, \Bbb Z[x]\,?\,$ You cannot say choose the "smallest positive" element without first defining what that means.

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking. I figured there is a definition for representatives that can be applied here.

Comment: There are effective ways of computing in quotients of $\,\Bbb Z[x],\,$ but they are much more complex than the Euclidean algorithm. Look up Hermite(-Smith) normal forms. See e.g. [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/613988/242)