# Properties of $\Bbb Q[X,Y]/(X-Y^2,Y-X^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> I would like to know if the quotient ring $R=\Bbb Q[X,Y]/(X-Y^2,Y-X^2)$ can be described in an easier way, i.e. is it isomorphic to something known?

If I denote by $x$ the class of $X$ and by $y$ the class of $Y$, then $x=y^2,y=x^2$, so that $x(x^3-1)=0$ so if the ring is a domain, then I have a third root of unity. Then maybe $R$ is related to $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3)=\Bbb Q(i\sqrt 3)$.

My question is a bit similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472235/describe-r-mathbbzx-x2-3-2x4). I don't know algebraic geometry, but maybe this is related to this topic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ring is just isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[X]/(X-X^4) \cong \mathbb Q[X]/(X) \times \mathbb Q[X]/(X-1) \times \mathbb Q[X]/(X^2+X+1) \cong \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q(\zeta_3)$

Comment: Thank you very much! How do you get $\mathbb Q[X]/(X-X^4)$ ?

Comment: If an ideal contains $Y-f(X)$, we can just forget about the $Y$ and replace it by $f(X)$.